# ElasticSearch querying nested objects not working as expected

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

So I am trying to search across nested objects in ElasticSearch and I am not doing something correctly as I get no results.

I run the following commands:-

**Create Index and Mappings**

```
PUT /demo
{
    "mappings": {
        "person": {
            "properties": {
                "children": {
                    "type": "nested",
                        "properties": {
                            "fullName": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "gender": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "index": "not_analyzed"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Add person document**

```
POST /demo/person/1
{
    "children": [{
        "fullName" : "Bob Smith",
        "gender": "M"
    }]
}
```

These all execute as expected. However, when I come to search on them as outlined in the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-query.html) I do not get any results.

**Query**

```
POST /demo/person/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [{
                "match_all": {}
            },
            {
                "nested": {
                "path": "children",
                "query": {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": [{
                            "match": {
                                "fullName": "Bob Smith"
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                }
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: are you maching by fullName but this field is saved as children.fullName inside Lucene. Just change to children.fullName :)

Comment: @WaldemarNeto - thanks that was the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to record the answer, the issue is that **all** queries and filters need the full field name. In the above example, the document is indexed as:

```
{
  "children": [
    {
      "fullName" : "Bob Smith",
      "gender": "M"
    }
  ]
}
```

To query `gender`, it must be accessed as `children.gender` and to query `fullName`, it must be queried as `children.fullName`.

All JSON data structures are effectively flattened by Lucene, which is actually the entire reason the `nested` type even exists, so:

```
{
  "children": [
    {
      "fullName" : "Bob Smith",
      "gender": "M"
    },
    {
      "fullName" : "Jane Smith",
      "gender": "F"
    }
  ]
}
```

becomes this with `object` type (the default):

```
"children.fullName": [ "Bob Smith", "Jane Smith" ]
"children.gender": [ "M", "F" ]
```

with `nested` type it becomes:

```
{
  "children.fullName": [ "Bob Smith" ]
  "children.gender": [ "M" ]
}
{
  "children.fullName": [ "Jane Smith" ]
  "children.gender": [ "F" ]
}
```

where the `{}` serve as nested document boundaries (they're not literally there, but logically they are).

As such, whether you're using nested documents or not, you need to supply the full path to the field name, even if the last part (e.g., `gender`) is unique to the index.

Of related interest: you should never use `nested` type when you only have a single object in the array. It's only useful when you actually use it as an array. If it's not an array, then the flat version serves the exact same function with less overhead. If some of the documents have a single, but some have more than one, then it also makes sense to use `nested`.